# How to display AdMob's real advertisement? I could display test advertisements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

## I think that many people have such a problem.

When asking with a stack overflow, there was an answer **"It will be displayed if payment information is completed"**. But now we can not set payment information unless we earn more than *8000 yen($100)*.

Since I was able to display test advertisements, I think these problems are not a problem of Unity or SDK. I think it is a problem within AdMob.

There were other answers. The respondent said that **"AdMob's advertisement unit will be displayed as time passes after it was made."** However, two weeks have passed since I made an ad unit!

Every answer was not what I was looking for.
When I was investigating other questions, I often found that the common answer is **"Do you mistake AppID and adUnitID?"**
I confirmed it over and over but there was no mistake.

There are no errors in the Unity Console.

I set personal information on the AdMob console.
I also set up payment service.

I do not know what to do. Please tell me.

---

Script↓

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;

    public void Start()
    {
         this.RequestBanner();
    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "My UnitID";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "My Ad Unit ID";
#else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

    bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

I am convinced that adUnitID is not mistaken.
When I changed adUnitID to the following string, test advertisement was displayed.

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

But when I made this string my own ad unit ID, the ad did not show up.

---

AndroidManifest.xml↓

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged with your
application's manifest, adding the necessary activity and permissions
required for displaying ads.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application>
            <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="My APP ID"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I think that this script and xml file are not involved in this issue, what do you think?

---

(Although it may not be necessary) Additional information↓

・SDK platforms → Android 8.1, Android 7.1.1, Android 6.0

・Google Play Services → installed (version 49)

・CMake → installed

・NDK → installed

・Support Repository → installed all

Comment: For those thinking of answering this question, be aware the OP asks the same question repeatedly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128486/more-opinions-please-i-can-show-test-banner-ads-but-i-cant-show-real-ads?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222625/i-can-show-test-banner-ads-but-i-can-not-show-real-ads

Comment: Your title says, 'I need more opinions.' However, questions that attract opinion-based answers are off-topic.

Comment: I just wanted to hear a lot of ideas to solve this problem.
If you know the solution to this problem please let me know. Please.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set bank information until you earn your first $100.
However you can and need to set all the other financial information and personal information. Once you have done this, it will display ads. Usually within a few hours.

Go to -> Payments
In payments, the bottom left section should contain an option to change settings.

This will open up a screen where you can add/ edit a payment profile. This is what is required.

Comment: Where can I write financial information and personal information?
Here? → https://imgur.com/a/pI2sjJN and https://imgur.com/a/S7rKXNz
Or is there any other place to write?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I already had those settings. There seem to be problems other than that.